# ASP.NET Quickest Way to Block all foreign IPs?

Tags: asp.net, ip, block, blacklist

I am wanting to block every country EXCEPT USA,Mexico, and Canada from my ecommerce site. From the research I have done, using an HTTPModule would appear to be the best method. However, this would require me going through a list of hundreds of ip ranges and woudl require quite a bit of code

Anyone have nay ideas on a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did block IP address range this would change as the get reallocated or taken up. Also its possible to use a number of services to spoof IP addresses or even to go out through routers / gateways in other countries even if you're not in the places you want.

You could try looking at the locale and / or time-zones set on the client machines. whilst this is not infallible and can be worked around (if the client knows what you're doing to block them),

They are en-us, en-ca, fr-ca, es-MX, it's the letters after the dash that you want, which are the [ISO 3166 Codes for Countries](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html). This may give you a start, it's not a infallible, but you're not going to get that anyway, but its a very light weight way of removing a fair amount of visitors.

Answer (score 0):

- IMHO, the *best* approach: application and/or network firewall (appliance) rules (having said that, if you have one, this may even negate the need to do IP address filtering entirely)
- [IIS](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)

Comment: I am using shared hosting. Accessing the IIS settings is not an option I have.